# RStudio fails to read GBP pound sign

Tags: r

After a bit of a gap I updated RStudio and all packages this morning.

I have a little function that I use to prettify currencies

```
currency <- function(n, k=FALSE) {
n <- ifelse(!k, str_c("£", comma(round(n,0))), str_c("£", comma(round(n/1000,0)),"k"))
return(n)
}
```

It now fails to parse - the problem is the £ sign.

```
Error in parse(text = lines, n = -1, srcfile = srcfile) : 

[path]/plot_helpers.R:72: 
25: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
71: currency <- function(n, k=FALSE) {
72:   n <- ifelse(!k, str_c("
                        ^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(con, warn = FALSE, n = n, ok = ok, skipNul = skipNul) :
invalid input found on input connection '/home/richardc/ownCloud/prodr/R/plot_helpers.R'
```

However I can run the code within the editor and it works fine. What is causing readLines to fail in this way ?

Comment: that function code parses fine for me. you might have an unterminated string on line at or above line 70

Comment: Thanks for helping. I should have been clearer - it used to parse fine for me too, and it is definitely the £ that causes readLines to fall over because if I change it for "GBP" it doesnt error.

Answer (score 1):

After some messing about today, I realise that the problem is in devtools. To recap here is a test project testencr.prj:

```
library(stringr)
library(devtools)

main <- function(n) {
  n <- str_c("£", n)
  return(n)
}
```

I can run the code fine from the console, but when I use devtools it barfs on the UTF-8 character:

```
> devtools::load_all()
Loading testencr
Error in parse(text = lines, n = -1, srcfile = srcfile) : 
  /home/richardc/ownCloud/test/R/test_enc.R:6:14: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
5: main <- function(n) {
6:   n <- str_c("
                ^
In addition: There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

But when I add a specific encoding into the DESCRIPTION

```
Encoding: UTF-8
```

It is all fine (this notwithstanding the project defaults are UTF8)

````
Loading testencr
There were 36 warnings (use warnings() to see them)```
````

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, specifically in a Shiny app (not the rest of the time). I managed to solve it by using this unicode instead of £:

```
enc2utf8("\u00A3")
```